# nextjs 14 app router render dynamic data on /blog page

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am creating a blog using next.js 14 App router. where I am facing issue rendering index page dynamically. here is my code

**app/blog/page.tsx**

```
import BlogItem from "@/components/Blog/BlogItem";
import GhostAPI from "@/lib/ghost";


async function getPosts() {
  return await GhostAPI.posts
      .browse({
          limit: "all",
          include: "tags,authors",
          filter: 'status:published'
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.error("GHOST ERROR", err);
      });
}


const BlogPage = async () => {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  return (
    <>
        <div className="mx-auto my-10 max-w-c-1280 px-4 md:px-8 xl:px-0">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-7.5 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:gap-10">
            {posts.map((post, key) => (
              <BlogItem key={key} post={post} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogPage;
```

this works correctly, it can list the blog post from the ghost cms api, but the problem is when I update the title of the post or publishes new post on ghost cms I need to rebuild the project in order to see the changes or new post respectively.

I studied the that `revalidate` can revalidate data every 60 second.

```
export const revalidate = 60
```

but I think there should be better way to render the dynamic data on server component dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your page to be dynamic, add [`export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic) at the top, like so:

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

import BlogItem from "@/components/Blog/BlogItem";
import GhostAPI from "@/lib/ghost";


async function getPosts() {
  return await GhostAPI.posts
      .browse({
          limit: "all",
          include: "tags,authors",
          filter: 'status:published'
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.error("GHOST ERROR", err);
      });
}


const BlogPage = async () => {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  return (
    <>
        <div className="mx-auto my-10 max-w-c-1280 px-4 md:px-8 xl:px-0">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-7.5 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:gap-10">
            {posts.map((post, key) => (
              <BlogItem key={key} post={post} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogPage;
```